# Added custom index for fields but ORDER BY still got couchdb no index exist for sort error hyperledger

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-composer

I checked https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/543 https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1640 and [ORDER BY not working in named query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919898/order-by-not-working-in-named-query) but they did not resolve my problem completely.

I added a custom index field in couchdb to sort by data.transactionTimestamp but my app still got the "no index exists for sort field" error.. Anyone knows how can I fix this? I only have GET and POST methods allowed for couchdb. I copy pasted my http://my_public_id:30984/channel1/_index records below since I dont have enough points to post picture. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank so much!

---

{"total_rows":4,"indexes":[{"ddoc":null,"name":"_all_docs","type":"special","def":{"fields":[{"_id":"asc"}]}},{"ddoc":"_design/26aaccbebd3e25d7dd8c6b8d7bcc25f6891cbfad","name":"26aaccbebd3e25d7dd8c6b8d7bcc25f6891cbfad","type":"json","def":{"fields":[{"data.transactionTimestamp":"asc"}],"partial_filter_selector":{}}},{"ddoc":"_design/c6dfa94edfc6620749e92789507a2ca946b98424","name":"c6dfa94edfc6620749e92789507a2ca946b98424","type":"json","def":{"fields":[{"data.transactionTimestamp":"asc"}],"partial_filter_selector":{}}},{"ddoc":"_design/e1d4f1e1212b6e8c3d6adabf71228868de791714","name":"e1d4f1e1212b6e8c3d6adabf71228868de791714","type":"json","def":{"fields":[{"transactionTimestamp":"asc"}],"partial_filter_selector":{}}}]}

Updated: [query file on hyperledger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxbLt.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide details of the version of composer you are using, whether you have a .qry file and what the contents of this file are.

Comment: @david_k the composer version is v0.16.2. and I have edited my post to include the statement in .qry file that caused the error. Thanks!

Comment: If you were running 0.19 or 0.20 versions of composer then it does automatic index generation to help in being able to add sorting to queries. I believe that fabric stored information differently in 1.0 so can't look at how it works now to help in your case. I would highly recommend not using composer 0.16 and move to 0.19 or 0.20